# DBAccess: Get array of any one property value

Tags: ios, objective-c, orm, dbaccess

I have dbobject like:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <DBAccess/DBAccess.h>

@interface GroupMember : DBObject

@property (strong) NSString *firstname;
@property (strong) NSString *lastname;
@property (strong) NSString *_id;

@end
```

How can I get an array of all group member's firstname?

Comment: DBAccess v1.6.7 now has a distinct call thanks to your question and feedback.  http://www.db-access.org/downloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not dealing with SQL but with whole objects, this requires a little bit of working round the problem, but it is possible.

```
NSDictionary* resultsGroupedByFirstName = [[GroupMember query]  groupBy:@"firstname"];
NSArray* names = resultsGroupedByFirstName.allKeys;
```

This is a fairly expensive call as it is having to do a fair amount of work in the background.  Although it is optimised slightly by using an index to detect changes in the column.

This should do the trick.

NOTE:

DBAccess v1.6.7 now has a distinct call thanks to your question and feedback.  http://www.db-access.org/downloads